# send data between two server sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have to make an app using C/PHP sockets on linux that sends data from one socket to other socket, like this.

I have server (**server_hosted)** hosted somewhere with an IP or domain name. It is running web application.
I have another server (**unknown_server**) running at my home (unknown IP).

Client send some information through web application hosted in **server_hosted** to another server running at my home (unknown IP).

I need a way to established a connection between **server_hosted** and **unknown_server**.

I was able to make connection between both using TCP socket. I made **server_hosted** as server listen to certain port says 8080 and **unknown_server** as client, which make open connection to **server_hosted**.

The problem comes when I have multiple **unknown_server** at my home. How can I made connection to same port? How many client can TCP/IP support?

Any ides how to make tunnel or connection between  **server_hosted** and **unknown_server**.

Is possible to do with curl or socket any better ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason to not just create a new socket and `connect()` to the other server?

Comment: Creating new socket will solve a problem. But for every server you need to have different port no. I have thousands of server at home need to connect hosted server.  I want to use just one port.

Comment: That's why I asked. Can you connect to the existing server port? Support your standard client-to-server protocol and a server-to-server protocol? For example, it's possible to write a web server that, if the first line isn't an HTTP request, processes the request differently.

Comment: I think no. I open new port like 8080 and try to connect my home computer to it. But when I have thousand of computer can I connect to same port, without closing connecting from any of the computer.